# Sharepoint customization wizard - can't deploy as a farm solution

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

Whenever I try to connect with the url (**Sharepoint customization wizard**, with option **deploy as a farm solution**) of the solution after creating a new sharepoint 2010 solution with the VS 2010 ultimate and I can't connect it, but I can access it in the browser.

I am running visual studio as administrator.

It gives me the error:

"Cannot connect to the Sharepoint site: *[site name].org.br*.
Make sure that the Site URL is valid, that the SharePoint site is running on the local computer, and that the current user as the necessary permissions to access the site.

Additional Information:

It is working without need to making package, automattically, (just pressing F5) on the localhost, but is not working in the network intranet solution.

Cannot connect to the Sharepoint site: *[site name].org.br*.
Make sure that this is a valid URL and the SharePoint site is running on the local computer. If you moved this project to a new computer or if the URL of the SharePoint site has changed since you created the project, update the Site URL property of the project."

Maybe it is required to use the Visual Studio Team Foundation Server to be able to make it to work.

**EDIT**: Was an error with the anti-virus at the network.

Now I can connect to the project, but cant deploy.
Now I have a problem when deploying it, it gives me a new error.
**Recycle the IIS application pool**:

**Error occurred in deployment step 'Recycle IIS Application Pool': Cannot connect to the SharePoint site: http://[website]. Make sure that this is a valid URL and the SharePoint site is running on the local computer. If you moved this project to a new computer or if the URL of the SharePoint site has changed since you created the project, update the Site URL property of the project.**

Comment: Are you running visual studio as administrator?

Comment: Yes, now I am experiencing a new problem.

Comment: Not even manually? Like making package, add SP-AddSolution, etc

Comment: It is working without need to making package, automattically, (just pressing F5) on the localhost, but is not working in the network intranet solution. is happening as showed above. =/ Yes, is importing as a package.